# Codeigniter/Jquery: How to update some form fields based on the value of the date input?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, variables, post, refresh

I have a form consisting of text inputs:

- date
- hours
- processed

The functionality I want is that when the date field is changed, there is a call to the database which fetches the hours and processed figures for that date, and populates the necessar form fields.

The overriding logic is: "If the values for this date exist, allow me to edit them. If they do not, then allow me to enter them."

Preferrably, I would like it to happen in the background - with only one php page.

I have tried:

```
        $( "#date" ).change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "#",
                data: {'date': $.('#date').val(), 'hours': $.('#staffhours').val(), 'items': $.('itemsprocessed').val()},
                complete: function(){    
                    location.reload();   
                }
             });
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, User pick a date, send it to server -> put the input forms (based on logic)
something like this?

```
$('#date_picker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    // or this.value
    $inputs = sendDate(dateText, items);
    $("#result_data").append( $inputs );
  }
});


function sendDate(date, items) {
    url = 'MyUrl';

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('date', date);
    data.append('items', items);

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function(html_data) {
            return html_data;
        },
        error: function(error_msg) {
                alert(error_msg);
            }
    });
}
```